# Show absolute element outside cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport Angular

Tags: css, angular, angular-cdk, angular-cdk-virtual-scroll

I have a `cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport` element and inside this element I have a relatively positioned div with an absolute positioned element inside it.. basically I want to be able to show the absolutely positioned item outside the `cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport` but its being cut off...

here is a stackblitz of the issue

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kavjsh

**component.html**

```
<div class="container">
  <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport itemSize="70">
    <div class="test" *cdkVirtualFor="let name of names">
      <p>{{name}}</p>
      <div class="test-item"></div>
    </div>
  </cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
</div>
```

**component.css**

```
p {
  font-family: Lato;
}

cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport {
  width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 600px;
}

.test {
  position: relative;
}

.test-item {
  position: absolute;
  background: black;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  left: 50%;
}
```

whats happening is this

[image]

and my desired result is this

[image]

I've tried all sorts of positioning configuration and I can not make it work?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I have exactly the same issue (showing a dropdown on an element of the list), and I don't want / can't reset the `contain: content;` property, as it is also important in the rendering of the elements (proper ellipsis on a long text).
I tried creating the floating part outside of the list, but it brings other issues (specific to our app).
Smokey, did you solve this issue at the time?

Comment: Did you find the solution, if yes then please post it.

Comment: @SantoshSonarikar no never found a solution

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below steps

- reset `contain` to 'initial' or 'layout'
- change `overflow` to 'visible'

```css
cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport {
   overflow: visible;
    contain: initial;
  
}

:host() ::ng-deep cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport .cdk-virtual-scroll-content-wrapper {
   contain: inherit;
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-miqwyw?file=src/app/app.component.css

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work since you lose the ability to scroll inside the container.. :(

Comment: It's interesting, do you mind I using javascript to slove it?

Comment: It seems that it indeed works, at least for Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Try with overflow visible in the test div or the cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport

```
cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport {
  width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 600px;
  overflow:visible
}

.test {
  position: relative;
  overflow:visible
}
```

Comment: Check if the style is being applied or it is overridden by other style

Comment: Try  !important and see

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kavjsh here is the stackblitz you can see for yourself